# Microsoft.WindowAzure vs Microsoft.Azure

Tags: azure-active-directory

does anyone even know what is the difference between these two DLL?

I noticed that Microsoft provide a lot of code sample http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn646737.aspx
which uses Microsoft.WindowAzure.....

While the one that I found in NuGet is 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient/

So which one is the correct one?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Azure was earlier called Windows Azure. You'll find that newer version of our assemblies/nugets are either using Microsoft Azure or simply Azure instead of Windows Azure - that's it.

For Azure AD you'll use the following two SDKs the most:

1. Active Directory Authentication Library: its job is to use the appropriate OAuth 2.0 flow, authenticate the user or the app (or both) and get a token from Azure AD (it does much more like caching, but that's the gist). ADALs are available for most platforms. The stable version of .NET flavor is here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/. We've also recently released the preview of version 3 with Xamarin support: http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2014/10/30/azure-ad-adal-net-v3-libraries-with-xamarin-support-now-in-preview.aspx
2. Azure AD Graph API client library: its job is to simplify calling CRUD operations on directory objects like Users and Groups and relationships between them instead of hand wiring the REST calls. Get the latest news on this here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aadgraphteam/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the samples' packages.config would indicate that [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/2.13.112191810) is the package they use (Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory).

What you pointed at is the client for their Graph API (see [this sample for graph API](https://github.com/AzureADSamples/ConsoleApp-GraphAPI-DotNet)).